# Flex content to fill height with Material UI clipped Drawer

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the sample Material UI code for a persistent clipped drawer. However, I want my content to fill the entire height of the content space.

I have created a sandbox showing the issue with the demo code, I have colored the background of the content section to be red. I want the content section to fill the entire height of the right hand side (i.e red to the bottom of the screen) this is because I want to place a canvas in that area for drawing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-quq2p?file=/demo.js

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this inside content, 100 viewport height might be your solution:

```
content: {
    height: "100vh"
```